# NEST ElasticSearch plural and singular search term

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm having difficulty looking for NEST ElasticSearch sample code that will treat singular/plural term as same. E.g. 'Shoes' and 'Shoe', 'Mouse' and 'Mice', etc. Need help on how to achieve this functionality. Thanks

Comment: what you need here is stemming. there are a lot of examples. but be aware that you will need the stemming for the specific language of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using snowball for stemming?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/snowball-analyzer/

Here is a link that discusses using snowball over the standard analyzer for your exact scenario.

[Lucene Standard Analyzer vs Snowball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875382/lucene-standard-analyzer-vs-snowball)

Comment: After implementing a similar feature this week, I found it was better for me to use KStem over Snowball since it was less aggressive with the stemming process.